# Variables might not have been initialized

Tags: java, variables, initialization

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ZodiacSign{

        public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int   Feb,March,ZodiacSign,Pisces,Aquarius,Aries,Taurus;

        int selection;
        System.out.println("Feb");

        System.out.println("Feb 1,2,3,4\n Feb 5,6,7,8\n Feb 9,10,11,12\n Feb 13,14,15,16\n Feb 17,18,19,20\n Feb 21,22, 23, 24\n Feb25,26,27,28\n March 1,2,3,4\n March 5,6,7,8\n March 9,10,11,12\n March 13,14,15,16\n March17,18,19,20\n March 21,22,23,24\n March 25,26,27,28\n March 29,30,31");
        System.out.println("Please enter your date of birth");
        System.out.println("Please enter your month of birth");


        selection = input.nextInt();
        if(Feb>= 19){
            ZodiacSign = Pisces ;
            System.out.println("Your zodiac sign is Pisces");
        }   
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Your zodiac sign is Aquarius");
        }
        if(March>=22){
            ZodiacSign = Aries;
            System.out.println("Your zodiac sign is Aries");
        }
        else
        { 
            System.out.println("Your zodiac sign is Taurus");
        }
            System.out.println("End of Program");



        }
}
```

Its giving me four errors:

```
ZodiacSign.java:19:error: variable Feb might not have been initialized
                if(Feb>= 19){
                   ^
ZodiacSign.java:20:error: variable Pisces might not have been initialized
                       ZodiacSign= Pisces ;
                                   ^ 
ZodiacSign.java:27:error: variable March might not have been initialized
         if(March>= 22){
            ^
ZodiacSign.java:28:error: variable Aries might not have been initialized
           ZodiacSign= Aries ;
                       ^
```

Answer (score 7):

You're never *assigning* a value to `Feb`, so what do you expect this comparison to achieve?

```
if (Feb >= 19)
```

Think about what you *really* wanted to achieve with that comparison, and then work out what you need to change to make it happen.

In general, you can't read from a local variable before it's *definitely assigned* - in other words, until the compiler can *prove* that you'll have been through some execution path which assigns it a value.

However, rather than trying to just make it compile with values assigned at the point of declaration, I would suggest you have a closer think about your overall design. You probably want to change Pisces, Aries etc to be enum values for example.

Additionally, Java code usually uses `pascalCase` names for local variables.

Answer (score 3):

You're reading variables which have never been written to, for example you read from `Feb` in the first `if` statement without ever having written anything to it.

Also, some of the code paths through your code leave `ZodiacSign` local variable uninitialized, which will produce the same error once you try to read it. Take for example this:

```
if(Feb>= 19){
  ZodiacSign = Pisces ;
  System.out.println("Your zodiac sign is Pisces");
}   
else
{
  System.out.println("Your zodiac sign is Aquarius");
}
```

If `Feb` is smaller than 19 `ZodiacSign` will not have been written by the end of the code fragment. The second conditional also may leave `ZodiacSign` unassigned.

What you're missing is actually using the value you read in from the input to set your local variables. That is, after

```
selection = input.nextInt();
```

you should use the value in `selection` to assign some useful values to `Feb`, `March` and so on. Then also make sure that `ZodiacSign` is assigned no matter which code path ends up being taken.

Moreover, there is a fundamental problem with your algorithm here. You do not need a variable for each month. You need just two variables for your input: day and month and a third for the zodiac sign.

Answer (score -2):

Change the following line

```
int   Feb,March,ZodiacSign,Pisces,Aquarius,Aries,Taurus;
```

to

```
int   Feb=0,March=0,ZodiacSign=0,Pisces=0,Aquarius=0,Aries=0,Taurus=0;
```

Method variables need some initial assignment before they are used. So do the same with all the other method variables.

Comment: They don't need a default value. They just have to be definitely assigned before they're read - which isn't the same thing.

Comment: I don't think that's the right approach though. (I'd also suggest using the more common terminology of "local variables" instead of "method variables".)