# variable vYourName might not have been initialized

Tags: java, initialization

i'm a beginner at java scripting only been coding for no longer than 3 weeks and i've been stuck on this for a while.

I get the error variable vYourName might not have been initialized, when i compile. This is what i have wrote so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetInput

{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);//create a scanner object to collect user input
    String vYourName;
    String vPraise;
    System.out.print("Enter your name? >>");


  if(vYourName=="giacomo")
  {
    vYourName= sc.next();
    vPraise =vYourName + " ,hi there";
}
    else
{
    vYourName= sc.next();
    vPraise =vYourName + " how are you";
}
    System.out.println(vPraise);
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variables might not have been initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284779/variables-might-not-have-been-initialized) and of course the ever-popular [How do I compare Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Just check the variable **vYourName**, You have not taken any user input for that nor even initialized that.
In this line-    if(vYourName=="giacomo")
You are trying to check a variable that is not initialized in any way

Comment: Go through line by line... You'll see it.

Comment: i fixed the problem guys but it ignores the if and else statement its always writing back to me hi there i only want that to appear when i write "giacomo" and everything else to be responded by how are you any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply initialize it before comparing it.

```
String vYourName = null;
```

or

```
String vYourName = "";
```

---

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your name? >>");
String vYourName = "";
String vPraise = "";
vYourName = sc.next();
vPraise = vYourName + ((vYourName.equals("giacomo"))? ", hi there" : ", how are you") ;
System.out.println(vPraise);
```

Comment: it fixed  the problem thanks! but one problem every word writes back hi there i only want the word giacomo to do that and all the others to write back to me how are you

Answer (score 0):

Your checking whether the vYourName string equals to something before you even read it. Furthermore, you should use the .equals() method instead of the ==.

Answer (score 0):

You have an instance variable `String vYourName;` with no value. What does the string hold? `"  "`, `"Hello World"`, ???

You always need to declare AND initialize any variables.

The proper way to do this would `String vYourName = "";` this will default it to `""` which holds nothing.